# File Upload not in /tmp

Tags: php

This sounds like a stupid question but, after uploading a file the file isnt in the location php said it would be.

First the simple test page:

```
<html><body> 
<h1><?=$_FILES['imgup']['tmp_name'];?></h1>
<?
        print_r($_FILES);
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
<input type="file" name="imgup" id="imgup">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Now, the print_r in plain text:

```
Array ( [imgup] => Array ( [name] => ace.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpEdfBjs [error] => 0 [size] => 29737 ) )
```

So no error, standard looking path, but /tmp has no such file. Further, running a find on my whole system turns up bubkis.

FYI: php.ini has

```
max_execution_time = 120
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

and the file I've been uploading is 29k

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The temporary file is deleted when the PHP script that received it has finished running : it is just a temporary file.

The PHP script to which you are posting the form -- upload.php -- should move the temporary file to a non-temporary location, using [**`move_uploaded_file()`**](http://fr.php.net/move_uploaded_file)

Basically, the idea is :

- The user uploads a file to your script,

  - That file is stored in a temporary lcoation.
- Your script works on that file :

  - Checks if the file is OK *(content-type, size, ...)*
- And if the file is OK, your script moves it to the permanent storage directory *(whereever you want)*

If the upload doesn't finish successfully, or if you don't move the file somewhere else, the temporary file is automatically deleted.

As a reference, you should read the following section of the manual : [**Handling file uploads - POST method uploads**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Quoting the part of it which is related to your problem :

> The file will be deleted from the
>   temporary directory at the end of the
>   request if it has not been moved away
>   or renamed.

Comment: ok, I added: $mv = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgup']['tmp_name'], "/var/www/testimg.jpg"); to the top of the file. $mv is always false, with no warning issued.  Anything I'm doing wrong there?

Comment: Does you webserver's user *(like `www-data` on some Linux distributions)* have the permissions to write into `/var/www/` ?