# file_exists yielding FALSE when syntax looks correct

Tags: php

I am trying to use `file_exists($_FILES["file"]["name"]))` as an `if` condition, but it always returns false. `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` is `$_POST`ed from a prior page. I had previously tried to use `isset()` instead, and while this worked, the `else` part of my `if` complex didn't work.

```
if(file_exists($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    echo "File exists.";
} else {
    echo "File does not exist."; //always returns FALSE even if image exists
}

if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    echo "File exists."; //always returns TRUE even if the image does not exist
} else {
    echo "File does not exist.";
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Harder for me to tell without seeing full source code for your form and handler. Plus, are you running this on a local machine, or via the WWW?

Comment: What does "the image exists" mean? `"name"` is the name of the file being uploaded to the web server; it certainly does not exist on the server!

Comment: Have you tried something like this `if(file_exists('upload/' . $_FILES['file']['name'])){` ? `upload` being the preverbial uploading folder. Also make sure your form field name is indeed `"name="file"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_FILES["file"]["name"]` holds the name of the file the client sends, the actual file is stored in a temporary location `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`

Comment: Thank you so much. This works perfectly. Was a real head scratcher for a couple of hours for me.

Comment: I don't mean to contradict, but isn't the OP looking to see if the file exists in the upload folder, rather than the `tmp` name? Since `tmp` names are server assigned random names.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (name has been changed to tmp_name)

name =  the name of the file submitted, not the filename of what php has stored it as on your server)

```
if(file_exists($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])){
    echo "File exists.";
} else {
    echo "File does not exist."; //always returns FALSE even if image exists
}
```

Comment: Also have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php if you are planning on moving the file somewhere

Comment: Thank you for the guide. I have code that moves the file to a more permanent home; my problem was nothing was being done because of the incorrect `if` condition.

Comment: @riista I have a suspicious feeling that even though you think it works, and I don't mean to contradict the answer, but my point is that, I think you want to check if the uploaded file exists in the `upload` folder, correct? `tmp_name` is a server assigned name and is given a **random** name/value and will change with each uploaded file, therefore I think (and correct me if I'm wrong here), you will be back to square one, as it were.

Answer (score 1):

I have a suspicious feeling that even though you think the given answers will work, **and I don't mean to contradict the answers**, my point is that, **I think you want to check if the uploaded file exists in the `upload` folder.** (Given the upload folder is called `upload`).

`tmp_name` is a server assigned name and is given a **random** name/value and will change with each uploaded file, therefore I think (and correct me if I'm wrong here), you will be back to square one, as it were.

**I quote:** *"The temporary file is deleted when the PHP script that received it has finished running : it is just a temporary file."*

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5516019/1415724

What I feel needs to be done is the following:

```
if(file_exists('upload/' . $_FILES['file']['name'])){

echo "File exists.";
} else {
  echo "File does not exist."; // or do uploading procedure
}
```

`upload` being the uploading folder.

Also make sure your form field name is indeed `"name="file"`

---

### The Logic

Take for example the code below. It will check if a file of the same name exists in the intended uploading folder, and if it does exist, it will throw an error.

It is not checking whether the temporary file name exists, but the actual intended file name itself.

If it doesn't exist, then it will upload it and not use the temp name for the upload, but the file name taken from a user's input.

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

---

### FOOTNOTE:

If by using `if(file_exists($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])){` instead of what's in my answer, then it will always upload while overwriting the actual intended filename to be uploaded, for example `image1.jpg`.

That logic won't work because it's checking if the `tmp_name` (temporary) file name exists in the intended uploaded files folder.

Since the temp name doesn't exist in the upload folder because tmp names are randomly given, it will overwrite `image1.jpg`

---

Therefore the use of the following code in the OP's original question cannot be used:

```
if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    echo "File exists."; //always returns TRUE even if the image does not exist
} else {
    echo "File does not exist.";
}
```

Comment: By default php file uploads are given a temporary name and need to be moved or renamed to the permanent location (if you want to keep them). The code you have above will never result in true, unless they have used move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'upload/' . $_FILES['file']['name']) prior to the test

Comment: @bumperbox Yes I agree with you 100%. However my point is, in my answer is that, I feel the OP needs/wants to check whether the file being uploaded already exists. If the OP wants to check if a `tmp` file already exists, will constantly be granted access. There is no mention of `move_uploaded_file` in the OP's code also, so that needs to be taken into account.

Comment: @bumperbox If by using `if(file_exists($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])){` instead of what's in my answer, then it will always upload while overwriting the actual intended filename to be uploaded, for example `image1.jpg`. That logic won't work because it's checking if the `tmp_name` (temporary) file name exists in the intended folder. Since the temp name doesn't exist in the upload folder because tmp names are randomly given, it will overwrite `image1.jpg`